# reCaptcha v3 on mobile devices

Tags: flutter

Could someone help me please?
I'm implementing Google Recaptcha V3, for Android and iOS applications.

I use the following command to get a return:

> bool ready = await GRecaptchaV3.ready("");

When running as a web application, it works normally because it is imported in index.html

> < script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=">< /script>

But, when running on the emulator, mobile applications do not interpret this index.html file, so the javascript is not loaded and my request does not return as expected.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Thiago , how did you managed to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`g_recaptcha_v3`](https://pub.dev/packages/g_recaptcha_v3) only supports the `web` platform. As you can see in the screenshot below, the pub.dev site only lists `web` as a platform for this plugin.

[image]